# Fibre of infinite loop space fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $F \rightarrow E \xrightarrow{\pi} B$ be a fibration with $\pi$ an infinite loop space map, I want to prove then that $F$ is an infinite loop space.

This is not true when $\pi$ is just a (not an infinite) loop space map.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept of a "loop space map" and can't find much online, what is it?

Comment: I meant to say that there are spaces $X_1$, $Y_1$ such that $X\sim \Omega X_1$, $Y \sim \Omega Y_1$ and there is a map $f: X_1 \rightarrow Y_1$ such that $\Omega f$ and $\pi$ commutes with respect to the homotopy equivalences.